# Can I Copy All the Wikis From One Trac To Another?

Tags: trac

We have an existing Trac installation for an old bunch of source code, and I'm creating a new Trac installation to support a new bunch of source code.  Most of the info we've built up over time in the old Trac installation's wiki is equally relevant for the new Trac wiki.

Is there a quick way to migrate the wiki data from the old Trac to the new Trac?

Trac version = 0.10.4

Comment: I would also like to recommend Redmine, which can merge the trac wiki into its system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trac-admin <trac-env> wiki dump <some-directory>` to dump the wiki pages to a directory, then use `trac-admin <new-trac-env> wiki load <some-directory>` to load the wiki pages into the new environment.

Note that I don't think this will preserve wiki page history.  If you want that, you can copy the database to the new instance and do a resync to the new repository.

I would also recommend upgrading to 0.11 if you can.  0.10 is no longer supported, and 0.12 is due out "soonish".

<sub>Disclosure: I'm one of the Trac devs</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [use `trac-admin`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) to [backup](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup) the wikis and then restore them on the other instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's all stored in the database, as far as I can remember. You should just be able to export the data from the old database and into the new one.